# Unable to update people picker field by default share point approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, people-picker, content-approval

I have document library in SharePoint 2013 environment, content approval is on. and I have copied the default SharePoint 2010 approval workflow and added one action to update the custom approver field once approval task is approved.

For first time if approver approves the task the WF will successfully update the approver field and the document gets its major version. When user tries to update the approved document and again requests for approval, this time when approver approves the task, the workflow through below error with with outcome as unknown error. the document continues to be in pending sate ever.

Error: "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information."

Please help me on this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the screenshots below to verify that if you select the correct custom approval field returned type:

[image]

[image]